# How to show cart modal after click on Cart icon in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, cart

I am creating a cart, I have already add product sucessfull but I do not know how to show cart modal when I click to my cart icon on navbar

This is my header, which is contain logo, menu and cart icon, it placed in `component/Header`

```
const Header = ({ basketNumber }) => {
 
  return (
    <Container>
      <Navbar expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Collapse className="nav-menu">
          <Nav>
            <Nav.Link href="/cart">
              <Image src={CartIcon} alt="Cart icon"/>
              {!!basketNumber && basketNumber > 0 && (
                <span className="basket-number">{basketNumber}</span>
              )}
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </Container>
  );
};


export default Header;
```

This is my cart modal, it placed in `pages/CartModal`

```
const Cart = ({fetchCartRequest, productInCart}) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userData");
    fetchCartRequest(userId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <BootstrapButton variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </BootstrapButton>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} size="lg">
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Cart detail</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          {!!productInCart && productInCart.length > 0 ? (
            productInCart.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <CartContainer
                  key={index}
                  image={item.image}
                  name={item.name}
                  price={item.price}
                  quantity={item.quantity}
                />
              );
            })
          ) : (
            <h4 className="center-title">Cart list is empty!</h4>
          )}
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <Button btnText="Checkout" onClick={handleClose} />
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};


export default Cart;
```

As you see my code in cart modal above I added a button to show the cart modal, But now I would like to switch to cart icon in my Header

How can I do that?
Please help me for this problem, thank you

Comment: Which component include both of them? I mean parent component of them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this button

```
<BootstrapButton variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
   Launch demo modal
</BootstrapButton>
```

You can use the icon here

```
<YourIcon onClick={handleShow} />
```

Comment: I know that but my modal and my header component in different folder, you can see my question detail above

Comment: ahaa, sorry for misunderstanding. You can use Ref maybe like this one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670067/open-modal-from-other-component-in-reactjs

Comment: In your example, what if I want to use the React Hooks there?